# Angularjs: Latin / Spanish character showing as junk character

Tags: angularjs, character-encoding

JS:

```
$scope.test = 'Amidación';
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-bind-html="test"></span>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Amidaci�n
```

Issue: I am getting the latin character ó in output as � junk character, i tried ngsanitize also but it didn't resolved. Any idea how it can render correctly ?

Note: Can't convert the latin character into ascii or hexadecimal because it is a Json data.

Comment: you need to replace charcter `ó` with `&ograve;`

Comment: Can not replace the character, since its a Json data

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to sanitize your text using `$sce`, for that you needto make that html as trusted using `$sce.trustAsHtml` method.

**Code**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', ["$scope", "$http", '$sce',
    function($scope, $http, $sce) {
      $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml('Amidación');
    }
  ]);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oFH6HcejE1zX5q2TlJsK?p=preview)

**Update**

More better way would be you could create your own filter that can be act as reusable component

**Markup**

```
<span ng-bind-html="test | unsafe"></span>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
});
```